# chdir on a file to use execl

Tags: c, linux

i'm programming on the command find in c and i'm blocked when i want to use exec on a file.

if it is a repertory it is simple, i just use chdir(path) but on file i have the error not a directory so i can't use exec on it

this is what i have

```
if (chdir(resultat[i])==-1){
                        perror("erreur changement de repertoire\n");
                        exit(1);
                    }

            execl("/bin/ls","ls",(char *)0);
```

resultat[i] is the path of my file

thanks for your help

Comment: Try to use english names in your code sample. And you might want to use `readdir` (then perhaps `stat`) instead of the above mess.

Comment: Would you mind paying a bit more attention to your question? What exactly are you trying to do? Why are you calling `ls`?

Answer (score 1):

*(I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do and I do not know what the rest of your code is doing, so this is only a shot in the dark...)*

Have you considered passing `resultat[i]` as an argument to `ls`? `ls` will probably do The Right Thing(TM) on it own. I.e. replace the snippet that you supplied with this:

```
execl("/bin/ls","ls", resultat[i], (char *)0);
```

I assume that you have already done all the needed work (e.g. `fork()`) to avoid your application terminating prematurely at the `exec()` call...

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is Linux (ls is linux only haha), so try using opendir first and see if you get a valid handle, then try to read one file out of it. If you get a valid filename, you can then check if its a file...

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reading_002fClosing-Directory.html#Reading_002fClosing-Directory

Comment: Actually `ls` existed for a long time before Linux, being part of the original AT & T Unix. These days you can find `ls` implementations pretty much on every OS...